# Mean value , maxim value of an urn-ball extracting problem?

Tags: probability

An urn contains n balls numbered from 1 to n. K balls are extracted without replacement.

a) Calculate the mean of the sum of its values. What does it happen if we extract them with replacement?

b) Calculate the probabiliy that the maximum value extracted is the mean value.

a) The expected value for a ball is  $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k·(1/n) = (n+1)/2$

If you sum the expected value of k balls then, the final result is $k(n+1)/2  $, with or without replacement, I guess.

b)?

Regards.

Comment: Your 'guess' on a) is correct.

Comment: Thanks drhab. By the way, what's wrong with the question that I'm getting -2. I don't get it . Thanks.

Comment: Neither do I. You showed effort on a) and despair on b). For me that's enough. I compensated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You helped yourself in a correct way. To make it more rigorous you can induce an ordering in the extracting and set $X_i$ as the number of the $i$-th ball that is extracted. To find is then $\mathbb E(X_1+\cdots+X_k)$ and with linearity of expectation and symmetry we find that this equalizes $k\times\mathbb EX_1$.

b) (without replacement)

If $n$ is even then the mean is not an integer so that the maximum
number extracted cannot equalize it. So let's assume that $n$ is odd with $n=2m-1$ for a positive integer $m$. Then $m$ is the mean.

If more than $m$
balls are extracted then at least one of them will have a number that
exceeds $m$ and consequently the maximum number will not equalize $m$. So it is time for a second extra condition: $k\leq m$.

In total there are $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{2m-1}{k}$
possibilities. Under the extra condition that number $m$ must be
extracted and that none of the extracted numbers exceeds $m$ we find
$\binom{m-1}{k-1}$ possibilities. This because it comes to choosing
$k-1$ numbers out of the set $\left\{ 1,\dots,m-1\right\} $.

So we end up with a probability of: $$\binom{m-1}{k-1}\binom{2m-1}{k}^{-1}=\binom{\frac{n}2-1}{k-1}\binom{n}{k}^{-1}$$

---

**Edit**:

b) (with replacement)

Comparing it with the former case again $n$ must be even, so we set $n=2m-1$ where $m$ is the mean. Here it is *not* necessary that $k\leq m$.

Setting $M:=\max(X_1,\dots,X_k)$ we have $P(M=m)=P(M\leq m)-P(M\leq m-1)$.

For a fixed $c$ the event $M\leq c$ is the same as $X_1\leq c\wedge\cdots\wedge X_k\leq c$ so that $$P(M\leq c)=P(X_1\leq c\wedge\cdots\wedge X_k\leq c)=P(X_1\leq c)^k$$ The last equation because the $X_i$ are iid. Applying that we find: $$P(M=m)=\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^k-\left(\frac{m-1}{n}\right)^k$$

Comment: I appreciate your help. According to my answer sheet the answer is $(m^k - (m-1)^k)/n^k $ . How do you equalize it to your answer?

Comment: It does not equalize my answer. This because the answer in your comment is for *with replacement* and mine for *without replacement*.

Comment: See my edit for the case *with replacement*.

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure about a couple of details. On the second line $X_1 < k$ ,  Should it be $X_1 < c$?. On the third line $P(X_i <x)^k$?
I don't understand the relationship between $P(M<m)$ and $P(M<c)$Can you explain it a bit more.And  why is the probability of $X_1<c$ equal to (m/n)?.

Comment: I don't see $X_1<k$ anywhere. What I said about $c$ is true for *every* $c$ so also for the special case $c=m$, and that is applied. Not $P(X_1<c)=\frac{m}{n}$ but $P(X_1\leq m)=\frac{m}{n}$.

Comment: Sorry. It was when I copied the page.  I don't understand the reason why $P(X_1<m) = m/n$.

Comment: Not $P(X_1<m)$ but $P(X_1\leq m)$. Realize that $X_1\leq m$ is the same event as $X_1=1\vee\cdots\vee X_1=m$. Probability: $P(X_1=1)+\cdots+P(X_1=m)=\frac1{n}+\cdots+\frac1{n}=\frac{m}{n}$

Comment: I understand it know. Thanks a lot for your support. It is really appreciated.

Comment: If everything is clear now and there are no other answers, then what prevents you to accept?